# How to form callback when using context.executeQueryAsync delegates in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Sorry for yet another question about callbacks.  In trying to solve this problem, I've run across about a million of them.  However, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this particular scenario.

I have the code below, which obviously doesn't work as delegates apparently don't return values (I'm learning as I go, here).  So, I know I need a callback at this point, but I'm not sure how to change this code to do that.  Can anyone help?

```
function MyFunction() {
    var ThisLoggedInUser = checkCurrentUser();
    //do some stuff with the current user
}

function checkCurrentUser() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var siteColl = context.get_site();
    var web = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
    this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser(); 
    context.load(this._currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.CheckUserSucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.CheckUserfailed));
}

function CheckUserSucceeded() {
    var ThisUser = this._currentUser.get_title();

    return ThisUser;
}

function CheckUserfailed() {
    alert('failed');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you have to rething the way you want your code because you cannot use ThisUser in MyFunction().

For example you could do that:

```
function CheckUser() { ... }

// then call the function to find the current user
CheckUser();

// then in  CheckUserSucceeded you call MyFunction()
function CheckUserSucceeded() {
  MyFunction(this._currentUser.getTitle())
}

// and now you can use ThisUser in MyFunction()
function MyFunction(ThisUser) {
  // do something with ThisUser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CheckUserSucceed won't return anything because it's asynchronous....
So you have to do something like that:

```
var ThisUser;
function CheckUserSucceeded() {
  ThisUser = this._currentUser.getTitle()
   // here you can call an other action and do something with ThisUser
}
```

You may also want to check the `$SP().whoami()` function from http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ and see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure how to implement this though.  It looks like you're turning ThisUser into a global variable, but I still can't get that to work because CheckUserSucceeded is running asynchronously.  Maybe my question should be more specific.  What changes do I need to make to CheckUserSucceeded and MyFunction to get a callback to work so that I can use ThisUser in MyFunction?